# Like button, description is replaced by Link Link Link Link when posted in my profile

Tags: javascript, facebook, button, share, facebook-like

I have a website, and I have added the like button with the `javascript sdk`.

This is the code

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

and this is the html code

```html
<div class="fb-like" data-href="WEBSITE URL" data-send="true"  data-width="450"data-show-faces="false" data-action="like"> </div>
```

I have also added the `og: meta` in the head

```xml
<meta property="og:description" content=" the description of my website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="url"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="pic" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="facebook id"/>
```

The problem is this:

When i click the like button on my website, I can see all the information (name,  pic, description), but when I go to the facebook profile, the description is replaced with this:

```
Link
Link
Link
Link
```

I can't understand where the problem is. Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: What does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) see for the URL you're liking?

Comment: this is the response: Response Code: 206
Fetched URL: http://ruzzle.beimomenti.it/
URL canonico: http://ruzzle.beimomenti.it/             fb:admins: Array of length 1
⍾ 1642659574
og:url: http://ruzzle.beimomenti.it/
og:type: website
og:title: HackRuzzle                                og:image:  display the image                       og:description: HackRuzzle è un applicazione che consente di migliorare il proprio dizionario di parole giocando a Ruzzle.
og:updated_time: 1359722264

Comment: Raw Open Graph Document Information
Meta Tag: <meta property="og:description" content="HackRuzzle &#xe8; un applicazione che consente di migliorare il proprio dizionario di parole giocando a Ruzzle." />
Meta Tag: <meta property="og:title" content="HackRuzzle" />
Meta Tag: <meta property="og:url" content="http://ruzzle.beimomenti.it" />
Meta Tag: <meta property="og:image" content="http://ruzzle.beimomenti.it/img/hr.png" />
Meta Tag: <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
Meta Tag: <meta property="fb:admins" content="1642659574" />

Comment: Graph API: http://graph.facebook.com/507995825911690
Scraped URL: See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL

Answer (score -1):

I've the same problem!

I've both Comment Plugin and Like box.

In like box if the user don't write any comment Fb post it on the user activity feed. But if the user write some content it put in the timeline with 4 lines of "like":

LinkLinkLinkLink

but on mouseover the title it show a popup with the correct preview.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="it-it" lang="it-it">
<meta property="og:title" content="Il menù dei cuscini"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.cibbuzz.com/comunicati-stampa/fashion-e-intrattenimento/il-menu-dei-cuscini"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Dopo i vini e gli oli, negli alberghi arriva la carta dei cuscini Si diffonde negli alberghi di qualità il “menù dei cuscini”, una lista dove..."/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.cibbuzz.com/images/loghi/logo-cibbuzz-portfolio.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Cibbuzz" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="130008293680636" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1051936195" />

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="100" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" data-href="http://www.cibbuzz.com/comunicati-stampa/fashion-e-intrattenimento/il-menu-dei-cuscini" data-force_wall="true"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=130008293680636";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

This come from Lint Tool :

```
Scrape Information

Response Code:  200
Fetched URL:    http://www.cibbuzz.com/comunicati-stampa/fashion-e-intrattenimento/il-menu-dei-cuscini
URL canonico:   http://www.cibbuzz.com/comunicati-stampa/fashion-e-intrattenimento/il-menu-dei-cuscini
Proprietà Oggetto

fb:admins:  Array of length 1
⍾ 1051936195
fb:app_id:  130008293680636
og:url: http://www.cibbuzz.com/comunicati-stampa/fashion-e-intrattenimento/il-menu-dei-cuscini
og:type:    article
og:title:   Il menù dei cuscini
og:image:   
og:description: Dopo i vini e gli oli, negli alberghi arriva la carta dei cuscini Si diffonde negli alberghi di qualità il “menù dei cuscini”, una lista dove...
og:site_name:   Cibbuzz
og:updated_time:    1359667404
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you want to express that you also have the same problem you can add a comment. If you wan't to find a solution for your problem I suggest asking your own question.